# Changing 9D back flow preventer valve on the boilers

Tags: repair, heating, boiler

I need to change the 9D back flow preventer valve on my boiler system and I want to avoid draining it.

Would it help if I close the 2 circled valves on the pic below?

[image]

Comment: They should isolate the top section, but the pump(blue) below might be a problem.  Is there a valve near the pump?

Comment: Is the back flow preventer between those two valves? It's hard to tell for sure, but the top left valve seems to lead into a vertical T, and there appears to be more plumbing (big blue thing) below it. If there's water coming into that, it's likely to flow out when you open the pipes. Maybe provide another picture at a better angle to show what's going on there.